# Automatic template class generation at compile time in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class, called `DynamicTexture` that takes in the `width` and `height` of a texture as template parameters. The parameters are used to instantiate a fixed size table (which is also a template class).

In my case, I am instantiating the `DynamicTexture` for various powers of two width/height (so 2x2, 4x4, 8x8, 16x16, 32x32 etc. all the way to 4096x4096). That means I have a lot of declarations like this:

```
DynamicTexture<2, 2>       dTexture2;
DynamicTexture<4, 4>       dTexture4;
...
DynamicTexture<4096, 4096> dTexture4096;
```

Now the question is, can I automate that process somehow? Furthermore, I am selecting the approxiate dTexture by quering a variable of type `unsigned int` (which shows the current size selected by the user) and then displaying the texture:

```
if (currTexSize == 2) dTexture2->show();
else if (currTexSize == 4) dTexture4->show();
...
else { dTexture4096->show(); }
```

Again, any way to avoid the long list of if statements?

**NOTE:** I am not sure how to phrase the title for this particular question. Feel free to re-word it.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not have a non-template class that takes size as a parameter?

Comment: @bdonlan: Lots of reasons, most of them not under my control :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now the question is, can I automate that process somehow?

You can do it with some advanced metaprogramming tricks:

```
template< int Width, int Height >
struct textures_holder
    : textures_holder< Width * 2, Height * 2 >
{
    typedef textures_holder< Width * 2, Height * 2 > base_t;

    void show( int currTexSize ) const
    {
        if( currTexSize == Width ) // or is it == Height?
            _texture->show();
        else
            base_t::show( currTexSize );
    }

    DynamicTexture< Width, Height > _texture;
};

template<>
struct textures_holder< 4096, 4096 >
{
    void show( int currTexSize ) const
    {
        _texture->show();
    }
};
```

then you would create an object of type `textures_holder< 1, 1 >` and get a variable for each of the power of 2 dimensions up to 4096.

Comment: +1 I like your thinking. :) I would probably go with an abstract base+ map, but this is neat.

Comment: Does the compiler work all of this out at compile time? Logically it should, but can it bust through all 12 levels of functions?

Comment: @Ayjay: Recommended minimum of recursively nested template instantiations that a compiler should handle is 1024 (that's four times more than, say, allowed throw specifications!)

Comment: Oh, of course the compiler will be able to *handle* this. The question is whether it will do it at compile or at run time? I'm going to run some tests

Comment: @Ayjay: What will be done at compile time and run time is well defined. Are you talking about some special optimization?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't mandate that all of the textures_holder::show function calls *must* be optimised out. Indeed, with optimisations turned off, VS2010 does just treat it as a standard function and calls each version in turn. I was wondering whether the compilers were smart enough to determine that the result of each function could be worked out at compile time and therefore optimise the entire set of function calls out. Indeed, VS2010 *does* perform that optimisation, and changes the textures_holder::show call to just call DynamicTexture::show on the correct object. That's pretty cool!

Comment: Note: of course that's assuming I pass in a constant known to the compiler at compile time. So, yes, I am talking about a special optimisation. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: @Ayjay: Ah, so you were talking about an optimization. Yes, it can do it, but its pretty useless since `currTexSize` will be a dynamic value most of the time. Try reading it from `cin` instead of having it be a literal constant, and see how it optimizes out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base-two logarithm of `currTexSize` to index into an array of different texture objects, provided their `show` method is virtual and derived from a common base class. This will be slower, but I think the improved readability will outdo the performance loss.

As for automatically declaring independently-named variables, there is no real template solution for this.